# Navigation Links in Django

Tags: python, html, django, url

How to set proper navigation on navigation bar to go back to the homepage or to go into further section such as e.g "contact" or "prices"? Ill show quick example what I really mean:

Home --  Prices  --  Contact

Being at the homepage I press "Home" button and of course it refreshes the site, because we are at the homepage. I press the Prices button and it goes into `127.0.0.1:8000/prices` and everything seems to be okay

- now we are in the prices section page -

Home --  Prices --  Contact

but now when i press "Contact" it goes to `127.0.0.1:8000/prices/contact`, but I would like that to be `127.0.0.1:8000/contact`, or by pressing now "home" it refreshes the site, its not going back into the homepage. Can you please give me tip what shall i do now?

my urls.py (whole project)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls') ),
]
```

my urls.py (application)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home-page"),
    path('prices/', views.prices, name="prices-page"),
    path('contact/',views.contact, name="contact-page"),
]
```

my views.py (application)

```
def home(request):
return render(request, 'home.html', {})
def prices(request):
return render(request, 'prices.html', {})
def contact(request):
return render(request, 'contact.html', {})
```

Comment: Could you please show the the HTML template that contains your nav bar? It sounds like the issue may be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more path, Like `home/` in urlpatterns..

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name="home-page"),
path('home/', views.home, name="home-page"),
path('prices/', views.prices, name="prices-page"),
path('contact/',views.contact, name="contact-page"),
```